# Get all possible timezones from UTC offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

I have the following value -
`GMT -0800`
 How can I get the list of all time zones sharing this offset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of listing timezones by offset, it's worth pointing out that the UTC offset for a given timezone changes due to daylight savings time for a lot of zones.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js"></script>

<script>


function initialise() {

    $("#offsetSelector").on('change', function (event) {
       showTimeZones();
    });

    var startOffset = -12;
    var offsets = Array.from(Array(48).keys()).reduce((acc, val) => {
        acc.push(startOffset);
        startOffset += 0.5;
        return acc;
    }, []);

    offsets.forEach((offset) => {
        var selector = document.getElementById("offsetSelector");
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = offset;
        el.value = offset;
        selector.appendChild(el);
    });

    document.getElementById("offsetSelector").value = -8;
    showTimeZones();
}

function showTimeZones() {

    var utcOffset = $('#offsetSelector').val();
    var timeZones = moment.tz.names();

    var result = timeZones.filter((zone) => {
        var tz = moment.tz.zone(zone);
        /* We'll make the assumption we're looking for the offset outside of DST */
        var currentOffset = tz.utcOffset(new Date('2018-01-01'));
        return  (currentOffset === (-utcOffset*60));
    });

    $("#list").empty();
    console.log('Zones:');
    result.forEach((zoneName) => {
      console.log(zoneName);
      var ul = document.getElementById("list");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = zoneName;
     // li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(zoneName));
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
}

</script>

</head>
<body onLoad = "initialise()">
<b>Offset (hours):</b>
<select id="offsetSelector">
</select> 

<br/><br/><b>TimeZone list:</b><br/>
<ul id="list"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/p9h5wgcr/

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this in two parts:

**1) Find a data set that contains timezone names & their offsets**

You could either manually compile this dataset (perhaps using data from Wikipedia), alternatively the NPM package [timezones.json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezones.json) seems to look suitable.

**2) Searching the list**

Given two inputs: initial timezone & offset (e.g. `GMT` & `-8`) you need to:

1. Search your dataset for the offset of the initial timezone (e.g. `GMT` is `+0`)
2. Add the two values together, e.g. `GMT-8` => `0 - 8 = -8`
3. Filter the dataset for values with an offset of `-8`

**Example:**

Lets say you have the contents of `timezones.json` from the NPM package above in a variable `timezones_file`

```
const timezones = JSON.parse(timezones_file);

// Step 1 above
function findOffset(timezone) {
   const matches = timezones.filter( zone => zone.abbr === timezone );
   return matches ? matches[0].offset : null;
}

// Step 2 above
function findByOffset(offset) {
    return timezones.filter( zone => zone.offset === offset );
}

// Answer to your question, accepts a timezone (e.g. 'GMT') and offset (e.g. -8)
function getListOfTimezones(initial_timezone, initial_offset) {
    const new_offset = findOffset(initial_timezone) + initial_offset;
    return findByOffset(new_offset);
}
```